# Rails models not being set on create or update

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm on:

Rails v4.2.11

Ruby v2.4.4

MySQL 5.7

I have the following rails model

```rb
# app/models/UnsupportedInstitution.rb

class UnsupportedInstitution < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bank_name, :reason

  validates :bank_name, presence: true
  validates :reason, presence: true

  has_many :unsupported_institution_routing_numbers
end
```

Here is the migration for the model:

```rb
class CreateUnsupportedInstitutions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :unsupported_institutions do |t|
      t.string :bank_name, null: false
      t.string :reason, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

which creates the following schema

```rb
create_table "unsupported_institutions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "bank_name",  limit: 255, null: false
    t.string   "reason",     limit: 255, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

This seems all pretty basic. However, when I enter the rails console and try to do:

```
UnsupportedInstitution.create!(bank_name: 'Hello', reason: 'World'})
```

I get the following error:

```
INSERT INTO `unsupported_institutions` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2019-12-11 00:24:22', '2019-12-11 00:24:22')

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'bank_name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `unsupported_institutions` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2019-12-11 00:24:22', '2019-12-11 00:24:22')
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
```

This also happens when I try to use the update method and when I try to create a new instance, set the values, and then save the model.

It's obvious the `bank_name` and `reason` attributes are not being set but I can't understand why. I suspect it has something to do with the "null: false" in the migration but I can't remove that since there may be sources other than my api accessing this particular endpoint.

Can anyone shed light on why this may be happening and/or what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Remove `attr_accessor :bank_name, :reason` from the model.

Comment: @Gerry That worked. Can you shed any light on why the `attr_accessor` method blocked the attributes from being saved? Maybe in a response below so I can accept it as the answer too. I read the docs on `attr_accessor` and I can't find anything that saves it would conflict with the database columns

Comment: Rails 4.x is no longer supported and may expose you to severe security risks. If this is a new project, or if this has *anything to do with actual money whatsoever* you should not use that. Likewise Ruby 2.4 is end-of-life [effective March 31, 2020](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/03/31/support-of-ruby-2-3-has-ended/) which is coming up fast. Switch to 2.6 if you can. It should be an easy upgrade path.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I'll def share this information with my team and make plans to upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating accessor methods which impede access to the methods ActiveRecord already generates for you.

Your definition should be:

```
class UnsupportedInstitution < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :bank_name, presence: true
  validates :reason, presence: true

  has_many :unsupported_institution_routing_numbers
end
```

Where `bank_name` will be auto-generated as a method *if* there is a corresponding field in the database, which there is if your migration ran successfully.